# Find installed programs/paths/registry key using powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a powershell script that can find the programs installed on my computer. I want to show info about where it is located, the executable file and which registry key it has associated.

I've used `HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*` and `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*`

The problem is that using those two, after that it doesn't give me the details to where it's installed or what is the main executable file.

Is there any registry that can show me that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the programs installed using MSI?  If so, the installation directory is tracked as part of the COM object.

Comment: @JohnZabroski sorry but I'm new to this, can you explain me that better?

Comment: InstallDude (installdude.com) on StackOverflow has tons of useful posts about this, but basically, Windows is pretty much built around COM and WBEM (WMI).  If you learn how to think like a COM data modeler/programmer, it all makes more sense.

Comment: i think `Get-Package` will show you most of that info. the `FastPackageReference` shows the registry uninstall location, `SwidTagText` has the install location, uninstall string, and other info. however, the other registry locations seem to be available only by searching the whole registry since that varies wildly.